# move and number files with same name in a new directory

Tags: python, bash, shell, mv

I have a directory with (a lot of) subdirs of the type

```
td.0000000
td.0000050
td.0000100
etc.
```

in each subdir I have a file called "density.cube"

I would like to move all the "density.cube" in a new subdir "td"

```
td/density0000000.cube
td/density0000050.cube
td/density0000100.cube
etc.
```

or at least

```
td/density.cube0000000
td/density.cube0000050
td/density.cube0000100
etc.
```

How could I achieve that ? I have basis in bash and python but it is obviously not enough...

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the find command.

```bash
find /your/path/here/to/the/parent/directory/that/has/all/the/folders -name density.* type f -exec cp {} /path/to/where/you/wanna/move/them +
```

-name matches the name of the files you want to get a hold of

-type f matches just files not folders with that name

-exec allows you to execute any commands on the results

cp the copy command in linux

{} substitute the results of the find command (your files that matched)

+ runs that exec command on every file that matched.

Answer (score 0):

this bash script should help you:

```
# create the td directory
mkdir td

# for every subdirectory of name td.*
for file in td.*
do
    # get its number
    number=$(echo $file | cut -d'.' -f 2)

    # and move the density.cube from that subdir to td with new name
    mv $file/density.cube td/density${number}.cube
done
```